# IndividualId as a SubscriberKey in Salesforce Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, contact, subscriber-key, individual

I want to ask your advice in organizing a new Marketing Cloud org. Our business process is organized in a way that we have Leads and later they are converted into Person Accounts. We track the consents of the clients in the Individual object. So, the idea is to have one master record for both objects. When it comes to the defining what Key to use for a subscriber, do you think that it's a good idea to link a SubscriberKey to the IndividualId for email send outs? Potentially, it'll allow us to track the subscription of a person despite the conversion. Do you think that there might be any hidden rocks inside this idea?

One important thing is that this org is shared with another department with its own sfdc org and they have ContactId as a SubscriberKey. Would it be a problem in case of having different keys in All Subscribers? In practice, these clients are different people and they cannot exist for both departments.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

While it works to some extent, that idea will cause problems down the road and once you start with it, this will get ugly to revert. So: avoid.

While you can of course send to any ID (Individual Id or an ID you create yourself), some MC Connect features won't really work.

e.g.: Journey Builder understands Leads, Users and Contacts as sendable Persons.

Whenever the Journey Builder UI will ask for "the person in the journey" - for example when you use "create a campaign member", expect problems when using IndividualId. And not only on SFMC side - you simply cannot put an IndividualId into a Campaign.

This is just one example, but it doesn't sound too outlandish. I wouldn't put my name under an implementation that essentially breaks such basic things in the standard MC Connect Product.

There is an official document on the ID problem that I would refer to, linked below. note how it does not recommend using IndividualId for what you are planning, but using ContactId consistently:

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&type=5&id=icx_b2c_crosscloudengagement_modeling_considerations.htm

Comment: Hi Jonas! Thank you very much for your reply! I got your point. Would it be fine then in terms of right platform usage to have Lead, Contact and Contact from another sfdc org SubscriberKeys? I think that this approach will work but when I make a send out, I can still check related Individual record of a Lead or a Contact in terms of Consents

Comment: Having separate multiple IDs is always problematic when trying to have a centralized view on things like permissions, history etc. Read the linked article. The advice there already is to not use leads and contacts at the same time. What you are suggesting is doing exactly that, and adding in a third Id (contactId from somewhere else) - that won't make it any easier.